# /var/run/lircd is not created when run as systemd service

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm configuring lirc in Raspbian. Here my systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Flexible IR remote input/output application support
Wants=lircd-setup.service
After=network.target lircd-setup.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lircd -n -H irtoy -d /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Irdroid_USB_Infrared_Transceiver_00000002-if00

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and here the lirc_options.conf:

```
[lircd]
nodaemon        = False
driver          = irtoy
device          = /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Irdroid_USB_Infrared_Transceiver_00000002-if00
output          = /var/run/lircd
pidfile         = /var/run/lircd.pid
plugindir       = /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lirc/plugins
permission      = 666
allow-simulate  = No
repeat-max      = 600

[lircmd]
uinput          = False
nodaemon        = False
```

It runs but it doesn't create the socket file /var/run/lircd.
Launching the very same command from shell:

```
/usr/sbin/lircd -n -H irtoy -d /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Irdroid_USB_Infrared_Transceiver_00000002-if00
```

leads to the correct behavior - i.e. the file is created and I can connect to the socket.

What would prevent this behavior when launched from systemd?

Comment: Maybe cause the default config file (lircd manpages) that the software will search for is `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf` not `lirc_options.conf` Maybe you will have to force the config file if you want to use a specific naming by passing as the last argument of your `ExecStart` line: `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lircd -n -H irtoy -d /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Irdroid_USB_Infrared_Transceiver_00000002-if00 /path/to/lirc_options.conf`...

Comment: I also have lircd.conf, but it contains the remote definitions. And it's read because the codes are sent correctly. The lirc_options.conf is created by the Debian package, I didn't create by myself.

Comment: That's fine, but you are running it as a daemon and it is supposed to read that config file, not `lirc_options.conf`. Maybe Debian changed that behavior and reading `man lircd` could give you a clue of what is the default config file this daemon expect.

Comment: I'm still confused... I pass the `-n` argument: it should *not* run as a daemon ("-n --nodaemon")

Comment: Anyway I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work: it complains "lirc_options.conf" doesn't contain remote definitions (they are in "lircd.conf")